# How to maintain consistency on write when using Event Sourcing on a Banking System

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

We have a system that holds credit balances, and we thought event sourcing would be a good fit.

Getting the current balance by reading from an eventually consistent projection works.

However, I still don't understand how to make sure that the debits/credits on the credit balance is valid/consistent without going through some database locking. This is very important to make sure they have enough credits to use, before actually processing the debit transaction.

Do we store a state that holds a consistent form of balance then lock it every time? Or is there a way to avoid going through pessimistic locking the balance state?

Comment: Are do you users use credits for? Are they buying products, or site access, or something?

Comment: @JohnWu it's purchasing transactional items, so you get the items after the charge/debit goes through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still don't understand how to make sure that the debits/credits on the credit balance is valid/consistent without going through some database locking.

In the usual case, there is locking.

One way to consider "aggregates" in domain driven design is that they are very close analogs of [course grained locks](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/coarseGrainedLock.html).

If our authoritative state for balance is "event sourced", then the actual thing that we lock is the history of credits and debits -- which is to say, the stream of events.

You can avoid pessimistic locking by using optimistic locking, which is to say a compare and swap approach when you perform a write.  Having an API that allows you to specify a particular point in the history (ex: a specific version number) is essential for this approach.  For example, [EventStore](https://eventstore.org/docs/dotnet-api/streams/index.html) supports this using an `ExpectedVersion` parameter.

It's almost analogous to what we do with Git; you make changes in your local working tree, but the official repository only accepts fast-forward commits.

> If there are high volume of concurrent debit transactions, am I think optimistic locking might not be effective since since each thread will result in an outdated state?

"It depends": high volumes of parallel activity updating the *same* event stream can certainly be a problem.  Often, you can partition the stream (by "accountId", or whatever); small consistency boundaries are an important element in concurrent processing.

> How do you think locking the stream of events would work?

The simple pattern is that we process a command by loading the original state of the target, computing a new state, and then performing a compare-and-swap to replace the original state with the new state.

When your state is a "stream of events", the logical sequence is the same.  However, because your stream has append only semantics, the compare-and-swap operation can be implemented more efficiently.

But the stream of events isn't a great data structure for queries, so we will normally "fold" them into some shape that is better for query (a volatile snapshot, if you like) and then use that to calculate the events that describe the new state.

The volatile snapshot can be cached, if you like.

The compare-and-swap operation can fail, if another writer performs an update that we don't see.  And so you'll have to think about how that failure should be handled.

Comment: If there are high volume of concurrent debit transactions, am I think optimistic locking might not be effective since since each thread will result in an outdated state?

Comment: How do you think locking the stream of events would work? I imagine there will be a persistent snapshot/state of the balance and we just apply pessimistic locking on it?